# Add an image to a vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I need to add an image to a vocabulary, not the taxonomy terms. Essentially, I need to add a field to the "Edit Vocabulary" page.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing/overriding `Drupal\taxonomy\Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyForm`, or implementing `hook_form_alter()`?

Comment: I haven't. I know what you mean. I guess my question would be, after altering the form then adding a field, where is it going to be stored?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could just use a single configuration object to store all VID:FID relationships, or one config object per vocab, if that suits your needs better. You could could also get creative, using plugins and a deriver, or define a very simple entity type just for VID companion images. It all depends on your use case and requirements. All things being equal, I would probably just use a single configuration object.